# How to use get-port package from a VS Code extension?

Tags: node.js, typescript, vscode-extensions

How can I use the [get-port](https://github.com/sindresorhus/get-port) package from a VS Code extension? I was able to use `get-port` in a standalone `typescript` sample project [here](https://github.com/hakonhagland/typescript-test-getport), but when I try to use the same `tsconfig.json` with a VS Code extension I get the following error in the developer extension host log file:

```
[2022-04-19 15:42:18.314] [exthost] [error] Activating extension undefined_publisher.vscode-test-getport failed due to an error:
[2022-04-19 15:42:18.314] [exthost] [error] Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /home/hakon/test/vscode/vscode-test-getport/out/extension.js from /usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/loader.js not supported.
Instead change the require of extension.js in /usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/loader.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at Function.<anonymous> (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:5:13331)
    at Function.<anonymous> (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/workbench/api/node/extensionHostProcess.js:104:32156)
```

The code can be found in the `tsconfig` branch [here](https://github.com/hakonhagland/vscode-test-getport/tree/tsconfig). The above failure happens when I execute the command "View Port" which the extension contributes.

The code uses the following `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "es6",
        "target": "es6",
        "outDir": "out",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "lib": [
            "ES2020"
        ],
        "sourceMap": true,
        "rootDir": "src",
        "strict": true
    }
}
```

I first tried the original `tsconfig.json` that comes with the `yo code` generated "Hello world" template (see the [main](https://github.com/hakonhagland/vscode-test-getport) branch):

```
 {
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "ES2020",
        "outDir": "out",
        "lib": [
            "ES2020"
        ],
        "sourceMap": true,
        "rootDir": "src",
        "strict": true
    }
}
```

which fails at activation (not when executing the "Show Port" command as the first example above did):

```
Activating extension 'undefined_publisher.vscode-test-getport' failed: require() of ES Module /home/hakon/test/vscode/vscode-test-getport/out/extension.js from /usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/loader.js not supported.
Instead change the require of extension.js in /usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/loader.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules..
```

Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Did you figure this out?  I am getting a similar error message when I changed from require to imports.

Comment: one up on this, I have the same problems. want to import and use it in vscode but can't. same error. any solutions?